# Angularfire2 and Rxjs Observable Not firing Catch and Complete Methods

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

i did an auth on my site, it works fine, but i want to handle errors, for testing i caused one for this purpose with this return from firebase: "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.". Im trying to write an RXjs observable to do that, with the following code:

```
private subscribleAuth() {
    this.af.auth
        .subscribe(
            auth => {
                this._auth = auth && auth.auth ? auth.auth : null;
                if (this._auth) {
                    this.loginState = 'logged';
                } else {
                    this.loginState = 'login';
                }

            },
            err => {
                console.log('error'),
                    this.loginState = 'error';
            },
            () => { console.log('done.') }
        );
}
```

My console never show the 'error' or 'done', so anything i put inside the err code doesn't work.

[image]

note: I know what causes that firebase return, i just want to know how treat it and why the code i wrote isn't worked as expected, when no errors are returned the site works as expected with the same observable.

I'm using angularfire2: ^2.0.0-beta.5 with Angular 2.0.0 final

EDIT 1:  [**even the official github project tells you to get the user as an observable and subscrible to it on Override configuration / No config Example app section..**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md)

EDIT 2: [**reported as an issue**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/566#issuecomment-250344817) and maybe it's really a bug, gonna keep this post updated. The workarround by now is using this code written by ***yashmurty*** on github:

```
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders } from 'angularfire2';
import { AuthBackend } from 'angularfire2/auth/auth_backend';

export class SocialmenuComponent {
    constructor(public af: AngularFire, private _authBackend: AuthBackend) {
        // this.af.auth.subscribe(
        this._authBackend.getRedirectResult().subscribe(
            (auth) => {
                if(auth) {
                  console.log(auth);
                } else {
                  console.log('User Not Logged In');
                }
            },
            (err) => {
                if(err) {
                  console.log('Error in auth.subscribe : ');
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log('No Error detected in auth.subscribe');
                }
            },
            () => { console.log('done.') }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean this line `this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth));`? But that's not what you're doing. Look at the very bottom: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md#cordova-case
They bind `.then()` and `.catch()` on the returned Promise from `auth().signInWithCredential(provider)`. That's how you can catch errors.

Comment: that's the apache cordova case, that should work too if i use the popup method, i'm using the redirect method so the page redirects to the provider page losing all the variable/states on memory (and the then funcion is called before the redirect), once again when it gets back to my page if i call auth.login would redirect to the provider page again in an infinite loop...

Comment: I can catch the error like this, but i still get exceptions thrown in error_handler.js and Subscriber.js - they seem to break the execution of the program - any way to silence/ignore those errors?

Comment: i don't know, that was just a workarround, from now im using the popup method until they fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any errors that occur when calling the `createUser` or `login` methods of the AngularFire2 `auth` observable are reported via the returned promises, not via the observable.

For example:

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

...
class MyComponent {

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {

    af.auth.createUser({
      email: 'someone@someplace.com',
      password: 'somepassword'
    })
    .then((authState) => { console.log('success'); })
    .catch((error) => { console.log('failure'); });
  }
```

If authenticating using a method that involves a redirect, you can do something like this ([jeffbcross solution from github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/566#issuecomment-260503675)):

```
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

...
class MyComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) fbApp: firebase.App) {

    fbApp.auth().getRedirectResult()
    .then((userCredential) => { console.log('success'); })
    .catch((error) => { console.log('failure'); });
  }
}
```

Comment: The errors are *not* reported via the observable, so the observer's error callback is never invoked.

Comment: removed my comments because they could confuse people, thanks cartant!

Answer (score 1):

I'm checking [`angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts) source code and I see it never calls neither `error()` nor `complete()` so the behavior is correct. It calls just [`next()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L165) on successful login.

This is just not how you're supposed to use `AngularFire.auth`. Calling `this.af.auth.login()` returns `firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState>` which is [rejected on missing credentials](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L82) or internally in [one of these cases](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L98) so the `Observer` (calling `subscribe()`) is not the place to handle error states.

Comment: So, im using login by redirect, every time the page loads if i call this.af.auth.login() it redirects the page and after the provider auth it gets back to my page, it gets called again to get the state and turns into an infinite loop by redirecting again, is there any other way to get the user logged state or the only way is using the popup method instead of redirect?

Comment: When you use Redirect instead of Popup - which you kinda have to use if you're doing mobile, then you won't be around to catch that error